# If $s^n\in S$ and $S$ is a multiplicative subset of a comutative ring, then $s\in S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to solve this question:

> Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of a commutative ring $R$ with identity. If $I$ is an ideal in $R$, then $S^{-1}\left(\operatorname{Rad}I\right) = \operatorname{Rad}\left(S^{-1}I\right)$.

the $\subset$ part is easy. In order to prove the converse, I need to prove first that if $s^n\in S$ and $S$ is a multiplicative subset, then $s\in S$, I think is true, because if $s^2\in S$, then $s^{-1}\cdot s^2=s$, and then by induction we will have $s\in S$, when $s^n \in S$ am I right?

**Remark**

$\operatorname{Rad} I=\{r\in R;r^n\in I$ for some $n\}$

**Edit**

Following the comments below, my approach is wrong, I need a suggestion to solve the converse, I proved also that Rad I is an ideal, maybe I can use this?

**Edit 2**

Take $s'\in S$, note that if $a/s \in$ Rad$(S^{-1}I)$, then $a/s=as'/ss'$ $\in S^{-1}$(Rad$I$), because $a\in$ Rad $I$ and $S$ is multiplicative.

Now, am I right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know that $s^{-1} \in S$? The statement you are trying to prove is just false; for example, the multiplicative subset of $\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $4$ doesn't contain $2$.

Comment: This is true for *saturated* multiplicative sets, that is, satisfying "if $xy\in S$ then $x\in S$ and $y\in S$"; for instance complements of prime ideals are saturated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in \operatorname{Rad}\left(S^{-1}I\right)$, i.e. $x^n=s^{-1}i \ (s\in S, i \in I)$. Denote $y=sx$. Then $y^n=s^{n-1}i\in I$ since $I$ is an ideal. Hence $x=s^{-1}y\in S^{-1}\left(\operatorname{Rad}I\right)$.